# Elasticsearch - проверка пересечения массивов

Tags: elasticsearch

В elasticsearch валяются документы с полем-списком:

```
"tags": ["ENUM_A", "ENUM_B", "ENUM_C"]
```

Требуется найти документы, в которых поле-список содержит хотя бы одно вхождение из списка в запросе (т.е. пример должен совпасть с `["ENUM_A", "ENUM_D"]` и не совпасть с просто `["ENUM_D"]`). Как это сделать? Фильтр `terms` не сработал (возможно, я его просто не очень правильно приготовил).

update: terms почему-то прекрасно работает на числах, но не работает на строках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ оказался довольно простым - Elasticsearch по умолчанию раскладывает строки на отдельные составляющие, применяет к ним lowercase-операцию, и ищет по ним. В моем случае я скармливал значения enum'ов напрямую в elastic, и он их хранил внутри в виде таких же строк, но в нижнем регистре, и фильтр `terms` искал среди значений иного вида, нежели я предполагал. Чтобы избавиться от подобной проблемы, необходимо выставить mapping `not_analyzed` для желаемого поля.

Дока: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_filter_with_text