# Найти и вернуть только уникальные значения в Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

Есть бэкенд на Node.js + Elasticsearch, и я хочу найти и получить только уникальные значения двух полей, как это проще сделать, есть производитель и есть модель устройства, т.к. есть много дублей нужно вернуть только уникальные пары модель/производитель , или в идеале конечно массивы, например
{
производитель1:
{модель1, модель2},
производитель2:
{модель1, модель2}
}
можно конечно это сделать на сервере или даже на клиенте, но хотелось бы завернуть всё на Elasticsearch.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно это сделать с помощью функций [агрегаций](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)
Для вашего случая будет выглядить так:

```
'aggregations' => [
  'manufacturer_list' => [
    'terms' => [
      'field' => 'manufacturer_filed',

    ],
    'aggregations' => [
      'model_list' => [
        'terms' => [
          'field' => 'model_field'
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Понял что делал не так, но есть один нюанс , у меня есть пробелы в названиях и агрегация идёт по словам, то есть если есть "Xerox 5222" то в "aggregations" ,будет два значения "Xerox" и "5222", как бы заставить агрегировать учитывая полное совпадение значения

Comment: для поля в индексе укажите index: not_analyzed [PUT mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) похожие проблемы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485619/ и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456072/

Comment: я уже немного почитал, даже нашёл интересную статью https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-aggregation-custom-analyzer , но меня прервали и я пока не разобрался с mapping , то есть правильно я понимаю что это типа настройки поля в базе данных , а не свойство поиска?

Comment: Да именно так надо указать серверу что бы он не использовал текстовый анализатор для этого поля, который разбирает на слова.

Comment: Вобщем попробовал, неработает, делаю мапинг на все поля и всёравно он выдаёт вместо "Model-1" два результата "Model" и "1". Уже хз что с этим делать, и через Sense и через Curl пробовал забивать мапинг,всё бестолку

Comment: Надо создать индекс с полями и параметрами до внесения данных.

Comment: Да просто я оказывается немного не так делал, надо было вызывать POST myindex , а я делал POST mapping

Answer (score -1):

Для `'terms' => ['field' => 'manufacturer_filed']` и `'terms' => ['field' => 'model_field']` нужно задать `size: 0`, иначе агрегация будет происходить только по 10 айтемам.